# How can I maximize the number of troops recruited from Visiting Monarchs?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-battle-warriors-way

When I defeat another country, I always recruit 10% of the their troops to join my army. But when I defeat a visiting monarch, the number of troops that I recruit seems to vary quite a bit. Naturally, I must recruit as many troops as possible, so what strategy can I use to recruit the most troops from a visiting monarch?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the number of troops you can receive from a battle is completely random. You will usually, if not always, receive more troops by fighting than by greeting peacefully, but aside from that, the number you receive is random.